# Percentage of cell cannot exceed 7%

Tags: excel, percentage, excel-2013, vba

I have an excel file that uses formulas to calculate the percent of incentive generated. I have been asked to set up cell (G14) to never exceed 7% no matter what the values of cells C6,D6 and E11 are changed to. This is weird for me because the percentage should either go up or down depending on those values.

Can anyone help me figure out what can be done to lock this cell from exceeding 7%? here´s a link to the file http://1drv.ms/1El030y

Thanks

Comment: It would improve the Question to outline what you prefer to happen if the calculation would exceed 7%.  For example, should the result be truncated to 7% in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set a maximum value on it:

```
=min(0.07,F14+$F$11)
```

Comment: Depending on the situation, sometimes that is better as `=max(0, min(0.07, F14+$F$11))` to avoid a negative percentage. Salary bonuses are one situation where this bears out; e.g. while good performance is rewarded, the bonus would never be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IF()` statement?

```
=IF(F14+$F$11>0.07,0.07,F14+$F$11)
```